# Using CakePHP 1.3, how do you handle HTTPS URLs on live and normal HTTP URLs on dev?

Tags: cakephp, ssl, cakephp-1.3

The project I inherited had all of the links hardcoded as "https" and my development environment doesn't recognize "https://somesite.internal-domain.com". Which means some things are occasionally broken.

Does CakePHP offer some way of producing formatted links that take into account whether or not an SSL certificate is available?

Comment: Do you need 'full' urls for all links? (including the domain name), because normally you'd only use relative links without the domain name (/mycontroller/myaction), this way you'll stay on the current domain, either 'https' or not.

Comment: One remark; Be sure to *test* the website via SSL before putting it live. Sometimes a browser behaves different when serving via SSL. If you don't test on a SSL environment you may get unpleasant surprising when deploying the website (yup, been there).

Comment: @thaJeztah There's a manifest of "sub-sites" that point to subdomain sites like http://subsite.mainsite.com

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does by default.
If you use relative or array links like

```
$this->Html->link('Some link', array('controller' => 'foo', 'action' => 'bar', ...));
```

you will see that cake uses http/https dependend on what you currently use.
That would be the way to go.

If you want to prevent one way just 301 redirect then to the other.
So if at one point you want to switch to https, redirect to from http to http (same link but with different protocol prepended).

Comment: Although this *is* the preferred way, I asked the OP if he needed 'full' URLs or only relative URLs, which is also possible using the option `'full_base' => true`.

Comment: You can still achieve that. Your way for link() - and with "true" as second param for all `$this->Html->url()` of course :)